# What does the following vector declaration means vector<vector<int>>v(100)?

Tags: stl, stdvector

How can I assign single size to a 2d vector?
Also what does this imply?

Comment: There are no 2d vectors, only vectors of vectors.

Comment: so what does 100 imply, which size?

Comment: v is a vector of *something*. What does 100 imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v` is declared to be a `vector` whose element type is `vector<int>`, and initialized to contain 100 such elements - all empty vectors. In other words, `v.size() == 100`, `v[i].size() == 0` (for `i` from 0 through 99).

If you want to initialize `v` to contain 100 vectors, each of which contains 100 `int`s, you can do it this way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{100, std::vector<int>{100}};
```

Comment: I think there is a slight error in your first line. The line should be "v is declared to be a vector whose element type is vector<vector<int>>. If it is so then what does a single size represent in a vector of vectors.

Comment: My statement is correct as written. `v` is of type `vector<T>`. `T` is its element type. Here, `T` happens to be `vector<int>`. A vector whose element type is `vector<vector<int>>` would be `vector<vector<vector<int>>>`